Raw UDP packet being dropped
I am learning raw socket programming in linux Ubuntu but i have a problem. My udp packet is not shown in Wireshark. I suspect that its being dropped by my router because of a mistake I made.
here is my code.
#include<iostream>
#include<sys/ioctl.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<linux/ip.h>
#include<netdb.h>
#include<linux/udp.h>

struct pseudo_header {
    uint32_t source_address;
    uint32_t dest_address;
    uint8_t placeholder;
    uint8_t protocol;
    uint16_t udp_length;
};

uint16_t calc_checksum(void* data, int len) {
    uint16_t* ptr = (uint16_t*)data;
    uint32_t sum = 0;
    while (len > 1) {
        sum += *ptr++;
        len -= 2;
    }
    if (len == 1) {
        sum += *(uint8_t*)ptr;
    }
    while(sum >> 16)
    {
        sum += (sum & 0xFFFF) + (sum >> 16) ;
    }

    return ~sum;
}

int main()
{

    char sendbuff[28];
    memset(sendbuff,0,28);
    iphdr* ip_header = (iphdr*)sendbuff;
    udphdr* udp_header = (udphdr*)(sendbuff + sizeof(iphdr));
    pseudo_header psh;

    ip_header->version = 4;
    ip_header->ihl = 5;
    ip_header->id = htons(5234);
    ip_header->protocol = 17;
    ip_header->tos = 0;
    ip_header->tot_len = htons(28);
    ip_header->frag_off = 0;
    ip_header->ttl = 45;
    inet_pton(AF_INET,"192.168.8.144",&ip_header->saddr);
    inet_pton(AF_INET,"192.168.8.1",&ip_header->daddr);
    ip_header->check = 0;

    ip_header->check = calc_checksum(ip_header,sizeof(ip_header));

    char checksum_data[20];
    memset(checksum_data,0,20);

    udp_header->source = htons(1134);
    udp_header->dest = htons(12345);
    udp_header->len = 8;
    udp_header->check = 0;

    psh.dest_address = ip_header->daddr;
    psh.source_address = ip_header->saddr;
    psh.placeholder = 0;
    psh.udp_length = 8;
    psh.protocol = ip_header->protocol;

    memcpy(checksum_data,&psh,sizeof(pseudo_header));
    memcpy(checksum_data + sizeof(pseudo_header), udp_header,8);

    udp_header->check = calc_checksum(checksum_data,20);

    int s = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_RAW,IPPROTO_RAW);
    if(s == -1)
    {
        std::cout << "Could not open raw socket" << std::endl;
    }
    int optval = 1;

    if(setsockopt(s,IPPROTO_IP,IP_HDRINCL,&optval,sizeof(optval)) == -1)
    {
        std::cout << "Could not set socket option!" << std::endl;
    }
    sockaddr_in dstinfo;
    memset(&dstinfo,0,sizeof(dstinfo));
    dstinfo.sin_addr.s_addr = ip_header->daddr;
    dstinfo.sin_port = udp_header->dest;
    dstinfo.sin_family = AF_INET;


    if(sendto(s,sendbuff,28,0,(sockaddr*)&dstinfo,sizeof(dstinfo)) == -1)
    {
        std::cout << "Packet could not be sent!" << std::endl;
    }

}


I have ran my program as root I suspect their is something wrong with my checksum calculation of the ip header or udp header. Please help.

As a way of reducing the problem area, could you write your packet's contents to a file in PCAP format? Then you can use standard PCAP tooling to inspect the validity of your packet and even step through the validation.

Print the errno and error message using strerror. Like std::cout << "Packet couldn't be sent. Error " << errno << ' ' << strerror(errno) << '\n';. Also, please copy-paste the output in the question. Also please return if any of those calls fail, you aren't returning.

@Botje I have done what you have asked it. As I suspected, my problem is that I have a bad checksum in my ip header.

Great! now you can reduce your problem to a few simple test packets with known checksums.

The difference between your calc_checksum and the algorithm in RFC 1071, section 4.1 is you do sum += ... where they do sum = ....

@Botje I have solved my problem thanks to you. The issue was within my checksum function.  I had to remove the while loop during the bit shifting part.

That sounds weird. What if (sum & 0xFFFF) + (sum >> 16) happens to overflow into more than 16 bits again? The while (sum >> 16) will keep going until at most 16 bits are set ...

@Botje Here is the exact code I implemented: sum = (sum >> 16 ) + (sum & 0xFFFF)  ; sum += (sum >> 16); these two lines seem to work, I guess their enough. Another mistake i did was not converting the udp length to network byte order( Big endian).
